# How to test inmemory caching using Caffeine cache manager? (i.e. getting the count of entries in cache after caching, cache evict)

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, java-8, caffeine

I want to get the details of entries in my custom cache after caching data or eviction of data.

I tried using actuator dependency to get 'actuator/metrics' path to get details but I'm getting empty tomcat server cache. There is no sign of my custom cache say myCache (the name which I passed into `@Cacheable` annotation value argument).

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with Caffeine and Spring Boot, so I assume you use those two products.

If you use a recent Spring Boot and Caffeine, statistics will be automatically available at `actuator/caches`. If not, double check you have the needed libraries on your classpath and no configuration that enables another cache or disables caching at all, like `spring.cache.type=none`.

If you don't use Spring Boot, but just Spring, you need to add a `CacheManager` to your configuration, otherwise Spring defaults to the `ConcurrentHashMap` which does not have cache statistics.

Comment: `actuator/caches` giving 404 error and yes I'm using springboot with caffeine. I have also created a custom caffeine cache manager to deal with different caches. @cruftex

Comment: @DevenderKumar, nobody can help further without knowing your actual code or configuration. You could extend your question with code snippets or put up a github project with a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for answering @cruftex , `actuator/metrics/cache.size` is working in my case and I'm getting cache size. The problem is solved.